# How to get the port a socket listens to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server

I am working on a project in which I am using a server to listen to mo multiple ports. In python, I have a list in which I saved all the sockets I need and then I do:

```
while True:

    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(sockets, empty, empty)
    for s in readable:

        message, address = s.recvfrom(4096)
        if address[0] == '192.168.0.9': 
            # do stuff
        if address[0] == '192.168.0.2':
            # do other stuff
```

The problem is I need to add another socket but I don't know the address the message is coming from a priori.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((server_host, server_port))
```

Considering the sockets are built like this, is there a way to access the `server_port` parameter from the final object to obtain something along the line of the following example?

```
while True:

    # get message
    # if message comes from port 1 do stuff
    # if message comes from port 2 do other stuff
```

Comment: Since you know the port when you bind the socket, why not just maintain a dictionary that maps sockets to ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.getsockname()` will tell you the local IP and port that a socket is bound to, eg:

```
while True:

    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(sockets, empty, empty)
    for s in readable:
        ...
        localport = s.getsockname()[1]
        if localport == ...: 
            # do stuff
        if localport == ...:
            # do other stuff
```